# Unary operator on char[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, visual-c++, unary-operator

I am trying to define the unary operator - on an array of char

```
Int operator - (const char *rs){
  Int b(rs);
  return  b;
}
```

but I am getting two error messages

> IntelliSense: nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type
>
> error C2803: 'operator -' must have at least one formal parameter of class type

I looked up the error code on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy7kx46x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but I still can't see what I am doing wrong.

I want to perform an operation like

```
-"1256ght78"
```

Comment: You try to overload operator `+`, but you want to use operator `-`..?

Comment: *"error C2803: 'operator -' must have at least one formal parameter of class type"* seems pretty much to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. One of parameters should have `class-type` for which you overload. You cannot overload operators for standard types.